# How to pass date as a parameter to MySQL Stored Procedure in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a `Date-Range-Filtration` in my web app. For that I'm taking an input using `date-picker` and passing that to my `controller to model`. When I'm echo it out it gives me the correct date value that I've selected from `date-picker`. But when I'm running my code, it gives me blank output. I'm wondering what is wrong with my code.

**Here is my SP code:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testDefects`(IN `startdate` DATE, IN `enddate` DATE)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT `defect_id`, `user_id`, `defect_rooms`, `defect_start_date`, `defect_subject`, `defect_responsibility`, `defect_time_frame`, `defect_followup_date`, `defect_assign_to`, `defect_notes`, `defect_details`, `defect_status`, `defect_updated_date` FROM `tbl_defects` WHERE defect_followup_date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Here is my Controller code:**

```
public function DefectFilterTest()
    {
        # code...
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['username'] = $user->username;

        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $data['groupId'] = $this->l->groupId($user_id);
        $data['group'] = $data['groupId']['0']->group_id;
        $data['title'] = 'Property Defects List';

        $startdate = $this->input->post('fromdate');
        $enddate = $this->input->post('todate');

        if($startdate == ''){
            $startdate ='1900-01-01';
        }
        if($enddate == ''){
            $enddate ='2100-01-01';
        }
        echo $startdate. "<br>";
        echo $enddate. "<br>";

        $data['defectslist'] = $this->p->testDefects($startdate, $enddate);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data['defectslist']);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();

        $this->load->view('template/header', $data); 
        $this->load->view('Property/defectList', $data); 
        $this->load->view('template/footer'); 
    }
```

**Here is my Model code:**

```
public function testDefects($startdate, $enddate)
    {
        # code...   testDefects
        $query = $this->db->query("call testDefects($startdate, $enddate)");

        if ($query->num_rows()) {
            $data = $query->result();
            $query->next_result(); 
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've googled it out, but I'm stuck, any kind of help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: dates are effectively strings so should be quoted in the sql or better use prepared statement and pass as parameters that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# code...   testDefects
$query = $this->db->query("call testDefects('$startdate', '$enddate')");
```